# Can one set the humidity level on a thermostat with the new Device Access Console?

Tags: nest-api, nest-device-access

I'm looking at the Thermostat/device traits available and the humidity trait appears to be read-only.  Is there any way to set the humidity level via the API?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested

Comment: Sure, I have looked in the google Device Access documentation, and all I can find is a read-only humity trait (https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/humidity) but no way to set it...  wondering if anyone else knows of a way...

Comment: As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824317/can-one-set-the-humidity-trait-on-a-thermostat-with-the-new-device-access-consol), this is a new feature request for Google.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the API is limited right now and does not allow adjusting the humidity settings in a Nest thermostat. (It also doesn't allow for reading additional temperature sensors connected to the thermostats.) I don't know of a way to request features from the Google API team but you could try them on social media and see if they respond.