# Can one set the humidity trait on a thermostat with the new Device Access Console?

Tags: nest-api, nest-device-access

I'm looking at the Thermostat/device traits available and the humidity trait appears to be read-only. Is there any way to set the humidity level via the API?
I have looked in the google Device Access documentation, and all I can find is a read-only humidity trait (developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/humidity) but no way to set it... wondering if anyone else knows of a way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just have a humidity sensor and there is no way to set the humidity.

Comment: Thanks Anjaneesh, I could set the humidity level in the previous nest API.  Is there a way to put this forward as a feature request?

Comment: Sure I can raise a ticket for feature request.

Comment: Hi Anjaneesh, any news on where this feature request might be?

Comment: Hi Anjaneesh, wondering if there are any news on this feature request?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AnjaneeshRayapati This is extremely important for whole house humidifiers in cold climate. When humidity is too high given outside temperatures, windows can break and insulation can mold. It requires daily or more updates to maintain recommended humidity levels. This has been a highly sought after feature for many years, which was previously solved with API. It has not been available for several years since. Please provide ticket location we can vote on or something. Ecobee has this built in and available through API. Am I going to have to switch? I can't handle another winter of this.